# What is this code doing? I'm new and still get confused in Java

Tags: java

I'm not sure what this does after the array is made.

I understand the array `A` is made at a size of 5 and filled with the 5 values of 1, 0, 3, 5, 3.

I don't understand the rest.

```
    int[] A = new int[5];
    A[0] = 1;
    A[1] = 0;
    A[2] = 3;
    A[3] = 5;
    A[4] = 3;

    double y = Arrays.stream(A).filter(x -> (x != 0)).reduce(1, (x, y) -> x*y);
```

Comment: If first filters out any value that's `0` and then multiples everything together. So in the end you'll get `double y = 45`

Comment: It'd be best to start off by reading the docs for each of the functions used (`stream`, `filter`, `reduce`) and taking it from there. You could also run just the `filter` or the `reduce` on their own so you understand what each is doing, or just dump out the results of each function inline.

Answer (score 1):

```
double y = Arrays.stream(A).filter(x -> (x != 0)).reduce(1, (x, y) -> x*y)
```

Lets break the above code into pieces and understand what each of them is doing.

**[Arrays.Stream(A)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)**  - Returns a sequential Stream with the specified array as its source which here is A.

**.filter(x -> (x != 0))** - this will return the stream of objects which match the criteria which here means all the numbers except 0.

**.reduce(1, (x, y) -> x*y)** - produces one single resultant value. Here the first parameter 1 is the initial value and also the return type of the resultant value and the second parameter is the operation to be performed which here is multiplication of all the values.

Hence 1*3*5*3 = 45 would be returned and stored in Y variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has an **error**. Variable `y` is used 2 times.

**Note:** Streams are very different from loops - in fact, another approach to loops. Using the term loops here just as an example.

In very simple words:

`filter()` has a condition, if the condition is false, that particular execution is broken. Sort of like `continue` in loops.

`reduce()` operations allow you to produce one single result from a sequence of elements, by applying repeatedly a combining operation to the elements in the sequence. In this case - multiplying.

In `stream()`, each intermediate operation is lazily executed, sort of provides one element from the array at a time to `filter()` and `reduce()`.

**Baseline:** It is just multiplying all the non-zero elements of the array and storing it into a variable.

More on streams here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html